# JOptionPane cancel button

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, cancel-button

Guys Im trying to use the JOptionPane but the cancel button is responding as if I entered a wrong input value and does not exit the programm. Any ideas whould be very useful!

```
int n = 0, k = 0;

Students stu = new Students();      

while (n <= 0) { 

     try { 
       n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(stu, "Enter the number of people","Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));

       if (n <= 0) {
        OptionPane.showMessageDialog(stu, "You have given a wrong input!", 
             "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       }    
    }

    catch (Exception e) { 
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(stu, "You have given a wrong input!",
               "Warning",  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
          n = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: consider posting full working code....

Comment: JOptionPane returns that as constant implemented in API

Comment: what's the condition for the program to exit?

Comment: Im trying to tell the program when the user presses the cancel button to exit

Comment: Look at the answer below, by A-SM. The input dialog will return null if the user presses the cancel button, regardless of what they have entered.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted:

```
int n;
String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
"Enter the size of the group", 
"Team Combination Finder", 
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

if (code == null) {
  System.out.println("This is cancel button");
  System.exit(0);
} else if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
  System.out.println("This is OK button without input");
} else {
  try {
    n = Integer.parseInt(code);
    if (n <= 0) {
      System.out.println("This is wrong input");
    } else {
      System.out.println("This is right input");
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("You must input numeric only");
  }
}
```

See if it works for you :)

Comment: This is the best answer. JOptionPane.showInputDialog returns null if the user presses the cancel button, regardless of what has been entered in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

After you have shown the OptionDialog you must use a break statement, in order to break the loop. JOptionPane doesn't know about your loop.

Or use

```
System.exit(ErrorCode);
```

instead of a `break;`

**update**

So I think what you want is this:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter name :  ", "New Record!", 

while (n <= 0) { 
 try {
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(stu, "Enter the number of people","Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   if(input == null || input.length() == 0)
   {
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(stu, "You have given a wrong input!", 
         "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      System.exit(0);
   }

   n = Integer.parseInt(input);

   if (n <= 0) {
    OptionPane.showMessageDialog(stu, "You have given a wrong input!", 
         "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   }    
}

catch (Exception e) { 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(stu, "You have given a wrong input!",
           "Warning",  JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
      n = 0; 
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens! 
                  if (stu == null) {
                      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(comb, "You have exit the program", "Exiting..",
                                                                              JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                      System.exit(0);
                  }

Comment: System.exit(ErrorCode) will exit the process. Wanted to give you a negative but can't do it.

Comment: Im just adding thing to my code to make it look better. The only thing I cannot do is the exiting with cancel button

Comment: @Mr.777, What do you think "exit the program" means?

Comment: @user2441143, so are you trying to write a dialog that asks the user to quit? You asked to exit the program, which can be achieved by `System.exit(..)`

Comment: I tried this if you see above in the comments but still nothing happens it remains in the loop

Comment: Seem my update. i think that is what you were looking for. You must check the result of the Inputdialog first.

Comment: yes this works because you changed the variable in String, but it does not work with int and I need n to be int. Is there a way to be done the same in this situation?

Comment: Seem my code. You get a string back. If the string is null, the user canceled. Otherwise you convert the returned string to an int by using Integer.parseInt(input) and you can do the additional error checking.

Comment: @Devolus Sorry man, thought, OP jsut wants to exit the part. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, I think mispelling `JOptionPane` (on line 11) should raise exceptions needlessly.

Comment: its ok in the code I just missed it when transfering it into here