# Customize JOptionPane

Tags: java, button, printing, joptionpane

I was thinking about to change `JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialouge(null,"Output");` in JAVA. Basically i need to add print button along ok button on dialogue so if user click on ok simply close it or if click on print button then proceed to actionevent against print button.

Comment: Best to create your own modal JDialog, complete with the buttons and functionality that you desire.

Comment: Or use the JOptionPane's showOptionDialog and add whatever custom button texts you want via an array of String as per the API.

Comment: No i am just wanting to  add button, when i print it, it may lead me to a action event.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use the [showOptionDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) method. Have a look at the Oracle documentation.

Here is the solution for closing the dialog when clicking "OK" : [JOptionPane cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895775/joptionpane-cancel-button).

Exemple where you have custom buttons :

```
    JButton but_print = new JButton("PRINT");
    JButton but_ok = new JButton("OK");

    but_ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             //Close the dialog
        }
    });

    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Test message", "Test", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{but_print,but_ok}, but_ok);
```

Comment: And how do you close the dialog?  Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing?  The Dialog object does not seems to be accessible to the actionListener unless you climb up the component tree.

Comment: nvm, I see that would be something like SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor((Component)e.getSource()).setVisible(false);

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for help guys. I just found even better thing and it is working right as i wanted.

```
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, s+"Print?",cnicstring,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
  //System.out.println("Pressed NO Button");
} else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
   // System.out.println("Pressed Yes Button");
    txtarea.print();
} else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
  //System.out.println("JOptionPane closed");
}
```